# Block/Allow from IP using DNS provider no-ip.org htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns, ip

I have a secure site (.htaccess = Deny from all) that I want to allow certain people access to

However, they are using mobile laptops and have dynamics IPs allocated to them by the ISP

So, I downloaded no-ip client which should give them a host which can resolve to an IP.

However, when I put

```
Allow from xxx.no-ip.org
```

in the .htaccess file, I still get the forbidden page.

I have other fixed IP locations allowed - and working - and I have tested that xxx.no-ip.org resolves to the IP I want by using http://www.webyield.net/ipa.php.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: as duskwuff pointed, no-ip does not help as client domain name is not used in the HTTP, and there's no way for your server to know it (except for reverse DNS which is not applicable to dynamic IPs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache `Allow` and `Deny` rules use wildcards (e.g, `Allow from *.example.com`), and as such work on reverse DNS. Your users' IP addresses are not reversing to the `no-ip.org` address (they're probably resolving to something specific to the ISP), so Apache is denying them access.

You'd probably do best to just give them all usernames and passwords, and use HTTP authentication (via [mod_authz_user](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_user.html) or similar) to grant them access.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using a script (modify to suit your needs):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Dynamic IP .htaccess file generator
# Written by Star Dot Hosting
# www.stardothosting.com

dynDomain="$1"
htaccessLoc="$2"

dynIP=$(/usr/bin/dig +short $dynDomain)

echo "dynip: $dynIP"
# verify dynIP resembles an IP
if ! echo -n $dynIP | grep -Eq "[0-9.]+"; then
    exit 1
fi

# if dynIP has changed
if ! cat $htaccessLoc | /bin/grep -q "$dynIP"; then

        # grab the old IP
        oldIP=`cat /usr/local/bin/htold-ip.txt`

        # output .htaccess file
        echo "order deny,allow" > $htaccessLoc 2>&1
        echo "allow from $dynIP" >> $htaccessLoc 2>&1
        echo "allow from x.x.x.x" >> $htaccessLoc 2>&1
        echo "deny from all" >> $htaccessLoc 2>&1

        # save the new ip to remove next time it changes, overwriting previous old IP
        echo $dynIP > /usr/local/bin/htold-ip.txt
fi
```

Than just cron it to generate a new line on the .htaccess file:

```
*/15 * * * * /bin/sh /usr/local/bin/.sh yourhostname.no-ip.org /var/www/folder/.htaccess > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Source: https://www.stardothosting.com